# How to bypass varnish cache on client?

Tags: caching, varnish, cache-control

I'm trying to get new content from a Joomla website or Yii web application, and we're using varnish on server side. How to bypass varnish cache control so that I can get the new content?.

I tried to add `?cachebuster=9999` to end of url but it's not working.

I can get the new content only when I'm using a proxy.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the port `8080` to bypass Varnish:

Example: `www.example.com:8080`